# C++11 - what does it mean to initialize a variable to a reference

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  private:
    vector<int> m_vec;
  public:
    vector<int> getFoo()
    {
      return m_vec; // returns a copy of m_vec
    }
    vector<int>& getFooRef()
    {
      return m_vec; // returns a reference of m_vec
    }
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  vector<int> x = foo.getFoo(); // init x with a copy of m_vec
  vector<int>& y = foo.getFooRef(); // y is a reference to foo.m_vec - no new copy is created
  vector<int> z = foo.getFooRef(); // what happens here?? Is the copy constructor invoked?
  vector<int>& a = foo.getFoo(); // what happens here?? Is `a` a reference to a copy of m_vec?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: As `z` is not a reference itself, it will be initialized with a copy of `m_vec`. Reference to `m_vec` will be returned from the method, but assigning it to `z` will execute the [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

Comment: thanks. that answers my question

Answer (score 3):

When you do this

```
vector<int> z = foo.getFooRef();
```

the compiler uses the reference on the right of the `=` operator to perform initialization of variable `z` to the left of the `=` operator.

The nature of the actual operation of initialization is determined by the left side, i.e. `z`. Since `z` is *not* a reference, operator `=` copies the content of the vector obtained by reference into `z`.